Can't add liquidity for invalid current price
Bug Description
If someone added liquidity with one token for out of range price, then, others can't add liquidity later.
In this case later liquidity providers can only add one token and not two tokens to pool.
ERROR
"The market price is outside your specified price range. Single-asset deposit only."

Add liquidity with only one token
Later users can't provide two token liquidity any more.
How resolve this issue ?
